# getsockopt doesn't return error when trying to connect to a closed port

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I try to use `connect()` & `O_NONBLOCK` to connect to a port in localhost asynchronously. In order to get the connect result, I use `getsockopt` to check the socket error status. I can sure no one listen to this port, so `ECONNREFUSED` should be returned. But in my test, this error may not be returned in some cases.

My test program:

```
int main() {
  uint64_t p = 0;
  while (1) {
    int fd = ::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert(fd > 0);
    int flags = ::fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    int ret = ::fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
    assert(ret != -1);
    sockaddr_in addr;
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(25400);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    ret = ::connect(fd, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr));
    assert(ret != 0);
    switch (errno) {
      case EINPROGRESS:
      case EINTR:
      case EISCONN:
        break;
      default:
        assert(false);
    }
    int epfd = epoll_create1(0);
    assert(epfd > 0);
    epoll_event ev;
    ev.events = EPOLLOUT;
    ev.data.fd = fd;
    ret = epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
    assert(ret == 0);
    epoll_event events;
    auto nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, &events, 1, -1);
    assert(nfds == 1);
    assert(events.data.fd == fd);
    int err;
    socklen_t optlen = static_cast<socklen_t>(sizeof err);
    ret = ::getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &err, &optlen);
    assert(ret == 0);
    assert(err != 0);
    ::close(fd);
    ::close(epfd);
    if (p++ % 10000 == 0) {
      std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

`assert(err != 0);` will be triggered.

Comment: You should only check `SO_ERROR` after select, poll, epoll, kqueue etc has returned the socket as ready for writing. You're not anything like it.

Comment: @user414777 Thanks for your reply, I change the test code, adding epoll. This problem still exist, and I have found the reason now~

Comment: @user414777 "*after select, poll, epoll, kqueue etc has returned the socket as ready for writing*" - or, is in an exceptional state.  Some platforms flag a failed connect as a writable state, some platforms flag it as an exceptional state. You should handle both cases.

Answer (score 0):

In this test code, I use `connect()` without `bind()`, in this case,  the source port is choosen by kernel. So the source port may be the same as destination port 25400. Due to the destination ip address is localhost, this TCP connection can be established in this case.

Comment: Have you changed the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` sysctl? You should have a lot of luck to hit upon the same port your socket was automatically bound to.

Comment: @user414777 I check the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` config in my server, the vaule is `10000 64999`. In my test program, the source port is 25400, which is in this range.

Comment: Which assuming that you don't have thousands of connections on that machine, means a ~1/50000 chance of hitting the jackpot ;-)